# $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu (E_{n,m}) \uparrow \int f d\mu$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $f \geq 0$ and $E_{m,n}=\{x :m/2^n \leq f(x) < (m+1)/2^n \}$

I need to show that as $n \uparrow \infty$

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu (E_{n,m}) \uparrow \int f d\mu$

My attempt:
I know that by fixing $n$, we have that on the set 
$E_{n,m}$ that $m/2^n \leq f(x)$ If we consider m to to finite , then $F=\mathbb{1}_{E_{n,m}}m/2^n$ is a simple function such that

$F \leq f \implies \int F d \mu \leq \int f d \mu \Leftrightarrow \sum_{m=1}^{K }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu(E_{m,n}) \leq \int f d \mu $

Now taking K to the limit we get that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu (E_{n,m}) \leq \int f d \mu$ .

It is clear that for a fixed n the sets $E_{n,m}$ are disjoint

First I need to show that the L.H.S is increasing in $n$ (I have already shown it is always less than equal to $\int f d \mu$. Then I also need to show that the lim  of the L.H.S is indeed $\int f d \mu$.

I cannot show that L.H.S is increasing in $n$ and that the limit is indeed the R.H.S

**Can you give me any hints on how to proceed. Please note that I am not looking for any complete solution**
Thank you

Comment: This seems like a nice start towards using the Monotone convergence theorem.  Have you tried using it?

Comment: @muaddib I do not want to use any fancy theorems, I am at the part of the book where they haven't introduced it, so probably the author wants me to come up with a more elementary solution

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked.  Has the integral above been defined (in your book) as the supremum of simple functions?

Comment: Yes, yes the integral is indeed defined as the supremum of functions of bounded  functions with finite support

Comment: Interesting question. You probably already received the hints you needed. Just be careful that the relation you need to prove might fail if f is allowed to assume infity value.

Answer (score 3):

> The integral is defined as the supremum of functions of bounded functions with finite support.

I would work directly from this definition to show the result.  If your function had been bounded and of finite support, then your above analysis is almost complete.  Each $f_n$ would be composed of a finite set of functions that as $n$ goes to infinity, obtaining the supremum in the definition.

However, your function is more general.  Here is how I would proceed.  In general, for $f$ to be integrable in the first place, it cannot have a) much mass off at infinity, b) much mass above a certain point.  In terms of integrals:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu = \int_{[-N, N]^c} f \chi_{\{f(x) \leq M\}} d\mu + \int_\mathbb{R} f \chi_{\{f(x) > M\}} d\mu + \int_{[-N, N]} f \chi_{\{f(x) \leq M\}} d\mu$$
where $[-N, N]^c$ is the complement of the interval $[-N, N]$.

Hopefully that is suggestive enough that you can finish from there, and flesh out the details of the above.

Answer (score 3):

**The L.H.S. is increasing with $n$**

Use the equality $$E_{m,n}=E_{2m,n+1} \biguplus E_{2m+1,n+1}$$ to get $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu (E_{n,m}) \le \sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^{n+1}} \mu (E_{n+1,m}).$$

**The limit is indeed the R.H.S.**

Prove that if $f$ is any simple function, you will have $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{m}{2^n} \mu (E_{n,m}) \ge \int f d\mu$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $f_{n}:=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m2^{-n}1_{E_{m.n}}$ then $f_{n}\left(x\right)=\lfloor f\left(x\right)2^{n}\rfloor2^{-n}$ for
a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

In general $2\lfloor a\rfloor\leq\lfloor2a\rfloor$ for each $a\in\mathbb R$ so that: $$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\lfloor f\left(x\right)2^{n}\rfloor2^{-n}\leq\lfloor f\left(x\right)2^{n+1}\rfloor2^{-n-1}=f_{n+1}\left(x\right)$$